# How I can to compare two strings and store the different items in Java?

Tags: java

I have two `LinkedList` and need to compare both and put into the ArrayList "nuevo1" the items in the `ArrayList` "viejo1" that not exist in the "nuevo1". Example:

```
viejo1 = {a1,a2,a3} ; nuevo1 = {b1,b2,b3};
Output = nuevo1 = {b1,b2,b3,a1,a2,a3};
```

I use this but unfortunately doesn't work:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Test{

    LinkedList <String> nuevo1 = new LinkedList <> ();
    LinkedList <String> viejo1 = new LinkedList <> ();


    public void copiarNuevo(){
        File nuevo = new File("/home/hellraiser/NetBeansProjects/new.html");
        try{
            FileReader frNuevo = new FileReader(nuevo);
            BufferedReader brNuevo = new BufferedReader(frNuevo);
            String lineaNuevo;
            while ((lineaNuevo = brNuevo.readLine()) != null) {
                nuevo1.add(lineaNuevo);
                System.out.println(nuevo1);
            }brNuevo.close();
        }catch(IOException e){System.out.println("Error -- "+e.toString());}
    }

    public void copiarViejo(){
        File viejo = new File("/home/hellraiser/NetBeansProjects/old.html");
        try{
            FileReader frViejo = new FileReader(viejo);
            BufferedReader brViejo = new BufferedReader(frViejo);
            String lineaViejo;
            while ((lineaViejo = brViejo.readLine()) != null) {
                viejo1.add(lineaViejo);
            }brViejo.close();
        }catch(IOException e){System.out.println("Error -- "+e.toString());}
    }

    public void compararArrays(){
        for(int i=0;i<viejo1.size()-1;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<nuevo1.size()-1;j++){
                if(viejo1.get(i).equals(nuevo1.get(j))){
                    nuevo1.addLast(viejo1.get(i));
                    System.out.println(viejo1.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.copiarNuevo();
        test.copiarViejo();`enter code here`
        test.compararArrays();
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is confusing. Let's say you have list1 = {a1, a2, a3} and list2 = {a1, b2, b3}. What is the operation and output you expect ?

Comment: Output must be: list2 = {b1,b2,b3,a1,a2,a3)

Comment: So you want the union of both lists, then?  From the explanation you provide here, you don't want duplicates, do you?

Comment: does it mean you simply want to append all elements from list1 that are not in list2 ? I.e. Union of two lists ?

Comment: @VicenteParra Pay attention to my example please, list2 contains a1, not b1.

Comment: Exactly, without duplicates.

Comment: Sorry but I think equals(...) doesn't work if you can't obtain your desired result. String exact matching should be done with sufficient care. In your case lines read form lines can be lengthy and different characters can result in bad behaviors. You have to process your input lines with different methods to get exact equal lines.

Comment: I know it, kiruwka, I believed it was a mistake

Comment: @VicenteParra No, it wasn't, I specifically put a1 in both lists. So in my example you want to see list2 = {a1, b2, b3, a2, a3 } , correct ? Do you care about the order.

Comment: Yes, kiruwka, it's correct

Comment: Are you then going to try saving the combined bookmark list so you can import it back into Firefox? If you are then your compare method is going to need to be a little more complicated

Answer (score 1):

No need to do any comparisons, as `Set` already satisfies the "no duplicates" requirement, and is a convenient data structure to use for this sort of problem.

You should use a `TreeSet` for this, so you can at least preserve the object's natural ordering.

```
public void compararArrays(){
    Set<String> union = new TreeSet<>();
    union.addAll(nuevo1);
    union.addAll(viejo1);
    System.out.println(union);
}
```

Comment: If equals(...) does not work in his algorithm, your algorithm won't work either!

Comment: `equals` is the correct way to compare two strings. If he has a problem with upper vs lower case or something he should take care of that before it enters his lists.

Comment: ...but they're `String`.  `String` has a well-defined `equals` and `hashCode`.

Comment: This could do what he wants, but it doesn't do exactly what he *asked*.  It will remove duplicates that initially appear in `nuevo1`, whereas he says he wants only to add zero or more elements to that list.

Comment: Since we now know he is comparing HTML pages, I no longer think removing all the duplicates is a good idea, Doing an export from Firefox myself I see duplicate lines of things like `</DL><p>` - yet I also think the OP's method in general isn't going to work for him (*if he plans on saving a new html page to import back into firefox*)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be doing things the hard way.  Here's about the shortest way to do what you asked:

```
public void compararArrays(){
    List<String> toAdd = new ArrayList<String>(viejo1);

    toAdd.removeAll(nuevo1);
    nuevo1.addAll(toAdd);
}
```

Note that that adds elements from `viejo1` that are not *initially* present in `nuevo1`, but it may add such elements multiple times if there are duplicates in `viejo1`.  To add at most one of each group of equal elements of `viejo1`, this should do the trick:

```
public void compararArrays(){
    for (String s : viejo1) {
        if (!nuevo1.contains(s)) {
            nuevo1.add(s);
        }
    }
}
```

*Edited to add:*

To do this with `O(n)` efficiency, without removing any elements of `nuevo1`, putting all added elements at the end, and preserving their relative order, you can do this:

```
public void compararArrays(){
    LinkedHashSet<String> toAdd = new LinkedHashSet<String>(viejo1);

    toAdd.removeAll(nuevo1);
    nuevo1.addAll(toAdd);
}
```

Comment: Looks nice, however Second approach yields O(N^2) performance.

Comment: They *both* have `O(nm)` complexity.  (`List.removeAll()` has that all by itself.)

Comment: very true. Quadratic performance, but less code. +1 for the first approach.

Comment: @kiruwka, or you can have it all if you choose the right data structure, as in the alternative I just added.

Comment: In my answer I use hashSet to get linear performance, with sacrifice of code clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Your source code should be fine  unless I'm missing what your are intending to achieve.

Meanwhile there should be a minor condition to fix in your for loops which is the stop condition that should go through the whole array whereas you are missing the last item.

It should be `i<viejo1.size()` instead of `i<viejo1.size()-1`:

```
public void compararArrays(){
  for(int i=0; i < viejo1.size(); i++){
    for(int j=0; j < nuevo1.size(); j++){
      if(viejo1.get(i).equals(nuevo1.get(j))){
        nuevo1.addLast(viejo1.get(i));
        System.out.println(viejo1.get(i));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Makoto's approach is the clean way to do it, however if you need to keep duplicates in your `nuevo1` you would need to iterate manually :

```
public void compararArrays(){
    Set<String> nuevo1Unique = new HashSet<>(nuevo1);
    for (String elem : viejo1) {
        if (!nuevo1Unique.contains(elem)) {
            nuevo1.add(elem);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(nuevo1);
}
```

Same O(N) complexity, just more code.

Comment: That has worse complexity than @Makoto's.  Each `List.contains()` is `O(n)`, and you perform `O(m)` of them, so that's `O(nm)`.  It should get the right answer, though, modulo order of elements.

Comment: @JohnBollinger wrong. I call `contains` on Set which is O(1).

Comment: You're right, my mistake.  To be more specific, though, `HashSet.contains()` is `O(1)`.  That efficiency is not a general characteristic of all `Set`s.  `TreeSet.contains()` is `O(log n)`, for instance.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I know, and yes, I mean hashset. And O(1) is only average (not guaranteed) performance. Anyways, your edit with linkedHashSet looks cleaner, although may give different results on original duplicates.

Comment: And that actually makes this approach *more* efficient than @Makoto's, because the complexity of adding `n` elements to a `TreeSet` is `O(n log n)`.  Makoto could make up the difference by changing to a `HashSet`, though.